# FME: Calculating Multiple attributes using Expression Evaluator

Tags: fme

I am new to FME, so please accept my apology if my question sounds too simple or stupid. I want to calculate two new attributes. Both attributes have different calculations. I am using Expression Evaluator. I can only calculate one attribute. For another attribute, I couldn't find any option to calculate another attribute. Am I supposed to use a new expression evaluator for another attribute? or is there any other way to calculate the new attribute?

Answer (score 0):

As with FME there is a million ways to go about.

either chain your `ExpressionEvaluator` like you suggested, or run them all in the same `AttributeManager` - this allows you to create/delete/update any attributes in your flow using the same mechanics. Just use the appropriate text og arithmetic editor